# Flutter: Convert Map to Json

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-http

I am trying to convert a complex map to Json String to pass to my Firebase Realtime Database.

The Map:

```
_data = {
  'name':{
          'description':'This is my description',
          'price': '700'
        },
  'name2':{...}
}
```

What I tried:

```
json.encode(_data)
```

This gives me an error:

```
Converting object to an encodable object failed
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the mistake! I was also using a for loop for putting the data in the map. However while using json.encode(for loop) doesn't work somehow. I removed it and now it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

It's your map,

```
data = { 'name':{ 'description':'This is my description', 'price': '700' }, 'name2':{...} }
```

To convert like this,

```
Var jsonData=JsonEncoder().convert();
```